# how to use "code ." command in python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automation

I have made a piece of code to automate making a new project. I ahve mangaged to create the file in a location I like, create the file and create a test python file. How would I open that file in vs code?

```
import subprocess,os,time

projectName = input("What is the name of the project?\n")
filename = "test"
fileEx = '.py'

os.chdir('../')
os.chdir('../')
os.chdir('../')
os.chdir('.\Documents\ ')
os.chdir('.\programs\ ')
project = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","md",projectName])
file = filename + fileEx
fileLoctaion = os.getcwd() + file
d = os.getcwd() + f'\{projectName}\ '
time.sleep(1)
os.chdir(d)
with open(file, 'w') as fp:
    pass
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import os
os.system("code NAMEOFFILE.py") ## the "code" command is the command used to open a file with vsc in a command line interface.
```

You can do the same thing with subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput("code NAMEOFFILE.py")
```